Export specific CAN messages from a MF4 file to ASC file using asammdf
I'm collecting CAN data to MF4 files using a CANedge1. Data is collected on both physical channels (Ch1 & Ch2). After loading the file using mdf = MDF('test.MF4'), I'm able to easily export the files as ASC using mdf.export('asc', 'test.asc'). The ASC file contains all the data from both Ch1 and Ch2.
I would like to expand upon this by:

Export data based on CAN Message ID (0x18123456 for example), or PGN.
Export data based on Ch1 or Ch2.
Stitch several MF4 files together to export a single ASC file.

I'm having difficulty locating the hooks/handles needed to make this happen despite reading through the documentation. I'm just getting started with asammdf so guidance would be much appreciated.
